# Read HTML code into R for data & text mining

Tags: html, r, data-mining, text-mining

I am trying to read the information located on this site into R for data and text analysis:

```
http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20142015/PL020916.HTM
```

I have tried to read the source code into R using the following packages and code:

```
library(XML)
theurl <- "http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20142015/PL020916.HTM"
tables <- readHTMLTable(theurl)

con = url("http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20142015/PL020916.HTM")
htmlCode=readLines(con)
close(con)
htmlCode
```

I am looking for an output that is a flat file of the information provided.

Comment: I don't use r, but saw something about this today, which might be what you're looking for: https://github.com/hadley/rvest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what info you are looking for from the page you've provided, but here's how you can read it in using rvest...

```
url <- "http://www.nhl.com/scores/htmlreports/20142015/PL020916.HTM"
library("rvest")
url %>% html()
```